# 'ViewController -> () -> VIewController' does not have a member named 'view'

Tags: ios, swift

I was setting up [BLKFlexibleHeightBar](https://github.com/bryankeller/BLKFlexibleHeightBar/) with swift. while I was writing `var flexibleHeightBar = BLKFlexibleHeightBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 100))`, an error as the title occurred.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is obviously related to your call to `self.view`, where, according to the error, the compiler thinks `self` is of type `ViewController -> () -> ViewController`, instead of what you probably expect it to be `ViewController`.

Where did you write this code?

If you wrote it in some `init` code or in a `static func` of your `ViewController`, then in that context `self` is not an instance of `ViewController` but something else. And given where you wrote that code, `self.view` does not represent you `ViewController`'s instance's `view` property, probably because `self` isn't created yet.

You need to move your code from  `init()` (where the `self` instance is being created but not ready yet) to `viewDidLoad` (once the `ViewController`'s `view` was just created).

---

#### Technical explanation on the `ViewController -> () -> ViewController` type

If you want to get a bit more technical and understand why the compiler expect `self` to be of that type in the error you had, know that in Swift, an instance method is actually also exposed as a class method which takes an instance as parameter and return the instance method (that mechanism is called "currying").

For example the `String` class has an instance method `hasPrefix` whose type is `String -> Bool`. It is also exposed as a class method that expect a `String` instance and return that aforementioned instance method applied on that instance; so that `String.hasPrefix` is of type `String -> String -> Bool`, and `String.hasPrefix("Hello world")("Hello")` is strictly equivalent to `"Hello world".hasPrefix("Hello")` (yeah I know that can seems strange at first, but it makes sense). *Of course in general you rarely (if ever) use this in your daily code, that's just a rarely used feature of Swift, but it's there.*

Back to your context, you were in the `init` method of your `ViewController`. `init()` is in fact a (special) instance method (no `static`/`class` before `init`) that, in that case, takes no parameter (`()`) and will return a `ViewController` instance, so its type is `() -> ViewController`. This instance method can also be interpreted as a class method (on the `ViewController` class) whose type is `ViewController -> () -> ViewController`, because behind the scenes it will be called with an (uninitialized, freshly allocated) instance of `ViewController` and will return a function (`init`) that, once called (with no parameter, `()`), will return the initialized instance of `ViewController`.

So that's where that `ViewController -> () -> ViewController` comes from in your error message above.

Comment: Even if that's a bit technical (and probably quite complex to understand for beginners as it involves internal mechanisms about Swift representation of instance methods), If you want to understand where that `ViewController -> () -> ViewController` type comes from in your original error I just edited my answer. That's not required information to know (don't freak out if you can't follow my explanations), but I feel that's always interesting to understand how stuff works and understand the error message better.

Answer (score 3):

The `frame` is supposed to be a CGRect, and you are not providing one. Your `frame: 0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 100` is just a series of numbers, not a CGRect. Swift has no idea what all those numbers are doing there. If you want a CGRect - and you do - you must say so:

```
frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 100)
```

Comment: I don't know whether that will solve the whole problem, but you certainly cannot proceed until you fix the issue I just described.

Comment: I am sorry. That is just a typo and the problem is still there. Any further help?

Comment: The problem is elsewhere. But I can only go on the code that you showed! If you want help, you must show the problematic code. In particular, you are doing this in a context - display the context.